# Not understanding why "if" is not triggered in modelsim vhdl sim

Tags: vhdl, programmable-logic

I am using a programmable-logic to decode a sequence of long or short impulses into latin letters according to morse code. I am using VHDL to describe our design, to be precise I'm using Quartus Prime for the design and ModelSim for the simulations. My CPLD is an ALTERA MAX-V 5M160ZE64C5.

I am using a on/off switch which corresponds to "state" in the code.

- When it is **off** ("state = '0'"), the CPLD is supposed to listen to a sequence of maximum 4 long/short impulses ("message" input) and store them in the "morse" logic vector for later. Also, as soon as the sequence is considered as long, a LED is supposed to shine, and a 14-segments display is supposed to show the "-" character.
- When it is **on** ("state = '1'"), the CPLD converts the previously stored "morse" logic vector into a latin character and displays it on the 14-semgnets display for as long as the "state" remains '1'. If it changes to '0' then it displays "-" again.

As you can see in the Modelsim simulation below, the LED shining part is behaving pretty well but as for the rest, it looks like two of our if statements are never triggered.

[image: Modelsim simulation]

The simulation was run using the following parameters :

```
force -freeze sim:/sauvezlesmorses/clk 1 0, 0 {25000000000 ps} -r {50 ms}
force -freeze sim:/sauvezlesmorses/state 0 0, 1 {9000000000000 ps} -r {18 sec}
force -freeze sim:/sauvezlesmorses/message 1 0, 0 {3200000000000 ps} -r {6.4 sec}
run 40 sec
```

... and here is the code.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity SauvezLesMorses is
    port
    (
        -- Input ports
        clk : in std_logic;
        message : in std_logic;
        state : in std_logic;

        -- Output ports
        seg14 : buffer std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
        lengthLED : buffer std_logic := '0';
        stateEvent : buffer std_logic := '0';
        messageEvent : buffer std_logic := '0'
    );
end entity SauvezLesMorses;

architecture SauvezLesMorses_arch of SauvezLesMorses is
signal morse : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0000";
begin
    morse2Latin : process(clk, message, state)
    variable count : integer range 0 to 3 := 0;
    variable clk_cnt : integer range 0 to 50 := 0;
    variable first : std_logic := '0';
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            if (first = '0') then
                seg14 <= "00000010001000";
            end if;
            if (stateEvent = '1' and state = '0') then
                seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                first := '1';
                count := 0;
                morse <= "0000";
                stateEvent <= '0';
                messageEvent <= messageEvent;
                lengthLED <= lengthLED;

            elsif (message = '1' and state = '0') then
                if (clk_cnt < 49) then
                    clk_cnt := clk_cnt + 1;
                end if;
                -- Inform user of the length of the current symbol
                if (clk_cnt <= 25) then
                    lengthLED <= '0';
                else
                    lengthLED <= '1';
                end if;
                count := count;
                morse <= morse;
                seg14 <= seg14;
                first := '1';
                stateEvent <= '0';
                messageEvent <= '1';
                clk_cnt := clk_cnt;



            elsif(state = '1') then
                if(count = 1) then
                    case morse is
                        when "0000" => seg14 <= "10011110001000"; --E
                        when "1000" => seg14 <= "10000000100010"; --T
                        when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                    end case;
                elsif(count = 2) then
                    case morse is
                        when "0100" => seg14 <= "11101110001000"; --A
                        when "1000" => seg14 <= "01101101000100"; --N
                        when "1100" => seg14 <= "01101101010000"; --M
                        when "0000" => seg14 <= "00000000100010"; --I
                        when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                    end case;
                elsif(count = 3) then
                    case morse is
                        when "0000" => seg14 <= "10110110001000"; --S
                        when "0010" => seg14 <= "01111100000000"; --U
                        when "0100" => seg14 <= "11001110001100"; --R
                        when "0110" => seg14 <= "01101100000101"; --W
                        when "1000" => seg14 <= "11110000100010"; --D
                        when "1010" => seg14 <= "00001110010100"; --K
                        when "1100" => seg14 <= "10111100001000"; --G
                        when "1110" => seg14 <= "11111100000000"; --O
                        when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                    end case;
                elsif(count = 4) then
                    case morse is
                        when "0000" => seg14 <= "01101110001000"; --H
                        when "0001" => seg14 <= "00001100010001"; --V
                        when "0010" => seg14 <= "10001110001000"; --F
                        when "0100" => seg14 <= "00011100000000"; --L
                        when "0110" => seg14 <= "11001110001000"; --P
                        when "0111" => seg14 <= "01111000000000"; --J
                        when "1000" => seg14 <= "11110000101010"; --B
                        when "1001" => seg14 <= "00000001010101"; --X
                        when "1010" => seg14 <= "10011100000000"; --C
                        when "1011" => seg14 <= "00000001010010"; --Y
                        when "1100" => seg14 <= "10010000010001"; --Z
                        when "1101" => seg14 <= "11111100000100"; --Q
                        when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                    end case;
                else
                    seg14 <= "11111111111111";
                end if ;    
                first := '1';
                stateEvent <= '1';
                lengthLED <= '0';
                count := count;
                morse <= morse;
                clk_cnt := clk_cnt; 
                messageEvent <= '0';


            elsif (messageEvent = '1' and message = '0' and count < 4 and state = '0') then
                if (clk_cnt <= 25) then
                    morse(count) <= '0';
                else
                    morse(count) <= '1';
                end if;
            count := count + 1;
            clk_cnt := 0;
            count := count;
            morse <= morse;
            seg14 <= seg14;
            first := '1';
            stateEvent <= '0';
            messageEvent <= '0';
            lengthLED <= '0';


            else
                seg14 <= seg14;
                first := '1';
                lengthLED <= lengthLED;
                count := count;
                morse <= morse;
                clk_cnt := clk_cnt; 
                stateEvent <= stateEvent;
                messageEvent <= messageEvent;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process morse2Latin;

end architecture SauvezLesMorses_arch ;
```

So, would you by chance know why those two ifs from code stated above

```
if (stateEvent = '1' and state = '0') then
...
elsif (messageEvent = '1' and message = '0' and count < 4 and state = '0') then
....
```

are never true?

---

---

**Last code update :**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee . numeric_std.all ;
use ieee . std_logic_arith.all;

entity SauvezLesMorses is
    port
    (
        -- Input ports
        clk : in std_logic;
        message : in std_logic;
        display : in std_logic;
        start : in std_logic;

        -- Output ports
        seg14 : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
        lengthLED : out std_logic := '0'
    );
end entity SauvezLesMorses;

architecture SauvezLesMorses_arch of SauvezLesMorses is
type state_t is (A, B, C);
signal state : state_t;
signal count : integer range 0 to 4 := 0;   
signal clk_cnt : integer range 0 to 21 := 0;
signal morse : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
begin


process (clk, start)
variable vectorDummy : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
begin
    if (start = '1') then
        state <= A;
        count <= 0;
        seg14 <= "00000010001000";
        morse <= "0000";
        lengthLED <= '0';

    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        case state is


            -- Idle, listening
            when A =>
                if  (display = '0') then
                    if (message = '1' and count < 4) then
                        state <= B;
                        seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                        count <= count;
                        morse <= morse;
                        lengthLED <= '0';
                        clk_cnt <= 0;
                    else
                        state <= A;
                        seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                        count <= count;
                        morse <= morse;
                        lengthLED <= '0';
                    end if;
                else
                    state <= C;
                    count <= count;
                    morse <= morse;
                    lengthLED <= '0';
                    seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                end if;


            -- Measuring impulse length 
            when B =>
                if (display = '0') then
                    if (message = '1') then
                        state <= B;
                        count <= count;
                        morse <= morse;
                        seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                        if (clk_cnt < 20) then
                            clk_cnt <= clk_cnt + 1;
                            lengthLED <= '0';
                        else
                            clk_cnt <= 21;
                            lengthLED <= '1';
                        end if;
                    else
                        state <= A;
                        if (clk_cnt < 25) then
                            morse <= morse;
                        else
                            case count is
                                when 0 => vectorDummy := "1000";
                                when 1 => vectorDummy := "0100";
                                when 2 => vectorDummy := "0010";
                                when 3 => vectorDummy := "0001";
                                when others => vectorDummy := "0000";
                            end case;
                            morse <= morse and vectorDummy;
                        end if;
                        count <= count + 1;
                        lengthLED <= '0';
                        seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                    end if;
                else
                    state <= C;
                    count <= count;
                    morse <= morse;
                    lengthLED <= '0';
                    seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                end if;


            -- Displaying converted character to user
            when C =>
                if (display = '0') then
                    state <= A;
                    count <= 0;
                    seg14 <= "00000010001000";
                    lengthLED <= '0';
                    morse <= "0000";
                else
                    state <= C;
                    count <= count;
                    morse <= morse;
                    lengthLED <= '0';
                    if(count = 1) then
                        case morse is
                            when "0000" => seg14 <= "10011110001000"; --E
                            when "1000" => seg14 <= "10000000100010"; --T
                            when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                        end case;
                    elsif(count = 2) then
                        case morse is
                            when "0100" => seg14 <= "11101110001000"; --A
                            when "1000" => seg14 <= "01101101000100"; --N
                            when "1100" => seg14 <= "01101101010000"; --M
                            when "0000" => seg14 <= "00000000100010"; --I
                            when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                        end case;
                    elsif(count = 3) then
                        case morse is
                            when "0000" => seg14 <= "10110110001000"; --S
                            when "0010" => seg14 <= "01111100000000"; --U
                            when "0100" => seg14 <= "11001110001100"; --R
                            when "0110" => seg14 <= "01101100000101"; --W
                            when "1000" => seg14 <= "11110000100010"; --D
                            when "1010" => seg14 <= "00001110010100"; --K
                            when "1100" => seg14 <= "10111100001000"; --G
                            when "1110" => seg14 <= "11111100000000"; --O
                            when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                        end case;
                    elsif(count = 4) then
                        case morse is
                            when "0000" => seg14 <= "01101110001000"; --H
                            when "0001" => seg14 <= "00001100010001"; --V
                            when "0010" => seg14 <= "10001110001000"; --F
                            when "0100" => seg14 <= "00011100000000"; --L
                            when "0110" => seg14 <= "11001110001000"; --P
                            when "0111" => seg14 <= "01111000000000"; --J
                            when "1000" => seg14 <= "11110000101010"; --B
                            when "1001" => seg14 <= "00000001010101"; --X
                            when "1010" => seg14 <= "10011100000000"; --C
                            when "1011" => seg14 <= "00000001010010"; --Y
                            when "1100" => seg14 <= "10010000010001"; --Z
                            when "1101" => seg14 <= "11111100000100"; --Q
                            when others => seg14 <= "11111111111111"; --unknown character
                        end case;
                    else
                        seg14 <= "11111111111111";
                    end if ;
                end if;


        end case;
    end if;
end process;


end architecture SauvezLesMorses_arch ;
```

**Corresponding Modelsim simulation :**
[image: Modelsim Simulation Updated]

So, now, the question is rather :

- Why does `clk_cnt` never increase (cfr state B)?
- Why does `count <= 0` not actually set `count` to 0 (cfr state C)?

Comment: Try probing more of your internal signals in modelsim to see what is going on inside.

Comment: Just did! Updated the code and uploaded the new simulation image (hope you can see it now, it's embedded, if you can't, it's right here https://s17.postimg.org/6p54uwr5b/Modelsim.png)

Comment: About the code update, so you don't have to read the whole thing again, I mostly only swapped to elsifs to change the priorities, and changed stateEvent & messageEvent to **buffers** so they would be easier to read in the simulation.

Comment: Why are you using `buffer`? Nobody uses that and it is (or at least was) not properly supported by synthesis software. Only use `in` and `out`. And you should probably write a proper testbench instead of forcing the signals.

Comment: Because we were taught we could use them if we liked. And the `buffer` values are all very coherent on the simulations so I'm guessing `buffer` is okay with my synthesis software. You are right about the testbench though...

Comment: For the record, clk_cnt should be a signal, not a variable. Variables are not 'local signals'. (I know you can get away with doing it, before someone says so...)

Comment: Allright, thanks a lot changing that straightaway.

Comment: Maybe just replace all variables with signals. You should monitor what is happening with the `Morse` register. It probably contains other data then you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well firstly look at this part

```
morse2Latin : process(clk)
    variable first : std_logic := '0';
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (first = '0') then
```

Every time the process is triggered, `first` is set to '0', so the if-condition is always true.

Then you should really separate the process into several pieces: preferably even one per signal. Combined like this it is difficult to read and thus difficult to maintain.

Then there is the finite state machine (FSM)..., or what i think is supposed to be an FSM. I tried to put some effect in decoding the states of your machine, but it is really weird. See the image:
[image]

You should consider writing a proper FSM... with state names and such. See a tutorial [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/implementing-a-finite-state-machine-in-vhdl/)

Comment: Very helpful and very nice FSM representation. But is the `variable first : std_logic := '0';` not supposed to set `first` to `'0'` only once? And what do you mean, cutting it into a myriad pieces, do you mean I should break each if condition into several basic ifs, just like your tree above? :) As advised, went for `out` instead of `buffer` eventually.

Comment: If you meant that, I just did change the code and reran a simulation above.

Comment: @CobalrScales I'm afraid I don't have the time to fully explain it now. To much work...

Comment: Don't worry you are helping a lot already, take your time and force be with you.

Comment: Changed all the code & now it does look like a proper FSM. Thanks to that, is is nearing it's working state. The problem is now that the count doesn't seem to increment properly nor the B state to detect impulse length. Working on it.

Comment: I did read the whole code again and again though, and it looks to me like Modelsim is mistaken because I cannot find my mistake. Could it be?

Comment: Solved, the last code update is working. I thought it was not because of improper simulation. A real testbench was required.

Comment: @CobaltScales don't use `std_logic_arith`as it interferes with `numeric_std`. Also, you don't need to do i.e. `temp <= temp;` if the signal doesn't change in a state.

Answer (score 0):

This only seems to show the E,I,S and H letters btw.
This might be due to those instructions:

```
if (stateEvent = '1' and state = '0') then
    morse <= "0000";
    stateEvent <= '0';
```

Cause stateEvent turn to 1 as soon as state does. So when tring to print the lettre you only print one of the **"0000"** signal of **morse** corresponding of the value held by **count**

Comment: But this condition only executes when `state = '0'`